# Keep getting informatica function error invalid string for converting to Date

Tags: function, datetime, informatica, to-date, to-char

I am trying to convert a nvarchar into a date, but I keep getting this error below

TT_11132 Transformation [Expression] had an error evaluating output column [Run_Date1]. Error message is [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:'20190304',u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')].

but my function doesn't include a 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'. Here is my function for reference.

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_date(RUN_DATE),'mmddyyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy')

Please Help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace everything with just `TO_DATE(RUN_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 1):

Samik is right, just use the `TO_DATE(RUN_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')`

What I'd like to add is some explanation why your function is wrong. So stripping it from innermost:

```
to_date(RUN_DATE)
```

Converts the RUN_DATE string to a `DATE` trying to guess the format as it has not been given. Let's call the result of it as `NewDate` and analyze further:

```
TO_CHAR(NewDate,'mmddyyyy')
```

Now this will convert `NewDate` to a string in the `mmddyyyy` format. Let's call this one as `NewString_MMDDYYYY` and see where it gets us. This leaves the final function as:

```
TO_DATE(NewString_MMDDYYYY,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

See the error yet? You tell Informatica to convert `NewString_MMDDYYYY` to a date. And you tell the function that it is written in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format - which obviously is not being used, as the TO_CHAR function was told to store it in `mmddyyyy`.

So, if your input `RUN_DATE` is in `YYYYMMDD` format, then all you need to do is `TO_DATE(RUN_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')`. If another formati is used by `RUN_DATE`, just replace the second argument accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation this will help when I use this function going further.